# for what $n$, $2^{2^n}-2^{2^{n-1}}+1$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

By checking for first few values, I figured out that the number
$$N=2^{2^n}-2^{2^{n-1}}+1$$ is prime for $n=1,2,3$ but for $n=4,5$ it is composite.
So are there any specifications on $n$ such that $N$ is prime?

Comment: For $n=6$, we have again a prime number , but for $7\le n\le 18$, we have a composite number. If there is a prime for some $n> 6$, it must be very large.

Comment: http://factordb.com/index.php?query=2%5E2%5En-2%5E2%5E%28n-1%29%2B1&use=n&n=1&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PR=on&PRP=on&U=on&perpage=20&format=1&sent=Show

Comment: My computational power is not big enough to help. Anyhow, seems interesting.

Comment: You know that even the question of primality for $2^{2^n}+1$ is a notorious open problem?

Comment: Note that $2^{2^n}=\big(2^{2^{n-1}}\big)^2$, so we can use $N=a^2-a+1$ where $a=2^{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: The next prime cannot occur before $n=25$ , hence must have more than $10$ million digits

Comment: Since, as @sirous suggested, $N=\left(2^{2^{n-1}}\right)^2-2^{2^{n-1}}+1= \left(2^{2^{n-1}}-1\right)^2 + 2^{2^{n-1}}=b^2+a^2$ for $n>1$, this [reveals a few details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) about $N$ prime.